# Google charts аннотации к бары

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Всем добрый день, прошу помощи по графику.Требуется вывести в подсказке информацию из ['operatorname'] и ['date'] . Выводится или то или другое

```html
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","mysql","mysql") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("met", $con); 

$sth = mysql_query("select * from `cena` left join `cnc` on `cena`.`cher` = `cnc`.`detal` left join `chertesh` on `cnc`.`detal`=`chertesh`.`id` WHERE `cena`.`operaciya` = `cnc`.`operaciya` and  (`detal`= $detal)  and (`date` >= '$datastart') AND (`date` < '$dataend') order by cnc.operaciya");

$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Операция', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Годная продукция', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Брак Операторов', 'type' => 'number' ),
    array('label' => 'Брак ОТК / Отладка', 'type' => 'number' ),
    array('label' => 'Оператор', 'type' => 'string' ),
    array('label' => 'Дата', 'type' => 'string' , 'role' => 'tooltip' ),
  

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['translate']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['colvodetal']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['brakop']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['brakotk']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['operatorname']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['date']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>

<html>
  <head>
<body>
    <!--Начало графика-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1, 
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 4,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2,3]);

      var options = {
        title: "График операций на изделие",
        width: 1500,
        height: 1500,
        legend: { position: "none" },
        bars: 'horizontal',
      };
      
      
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_material"));
      
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  </script>
<div id="barchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 900px;"></div>
    <!--Конец графика-->
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, содержимое переменной $jsonTable.

Comment: {"v":9},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"1 \u0444\u0440\u0435\u0437\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0430\u044f(\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u043e d92h11)"}

Comment: JSON, вроде как не валидный.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос таким образом

```js
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1, 
                       { sourceColumn: 4,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                         { sourceColumn: 5,
                         type: "date",
                         role: "annotation",
                         fontSize: 18, },
                       2,3]);
```